# Resolving ITMS-90626 Errors for Localized Custom Intent Titles and Descriptions in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, siri, sirishortcuts

I'm facing an issue with Apple's `intentdefinition` file while adding a new intent for `Shortcuts` integration in my app.

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot below, I've filled out the `Title` and `Description` fields.
However, after uploading to TestFlight, I received the following email:

```
Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - Localized title for custom intent: 'GoHome' not found for locale: ko
ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - Localized title for custom intent: 'GoFavorite' not found for locale: ko
ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - Localized title for custom intent: 'GoDriveMode' not found for locale: ko
After you’ve corrected the issues, you can upload a new binary to App Store Connect.
Best regards,
The App Store Team
```

I assumed this issue was due to not having localized the intentdefinition file, so I added localization as follows and re-uploaded to TestFlight.

[image]

However, I received the same type of email (with slight differences; the failed items increased, and the locale changed from ko to ko_KR).

```
Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - Localized description for custom intent: 'GoDriveMode' not found for locale: ko_KR
ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - Localized title for custom intent: 'GoFavorite' not found for locale: ko_KR
ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - Localized description for custom intent: 'GoHome' not found for locale: ko_KR
ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - Localized title for custom intent: 'GoDriveMode' not found for locale: ko_KR
ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - Localized title for custom intent: 'GoHome' not found for locale: ko_KR
ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - Localized description for custom intent: 'GoFavorite' not found for locale: ko_KR
After you’ve corrected the issues, you can upload a new binary to App Store Connect.
Best regards,
The App Store Team
```

I've tried the following to resolve this issue but still received the same email:

- Deleting and re-adding localization from the Base
- Comparing my intentdefinition file with another from a sample project
- Disabling the `intent is eligible for Siri Suggestions` option

I've searched and tried various things, but frankly, I'm not sure what else to do at this point.

If anyone has any information, solutions, or similar experiences related to this issue, I'd be eager to hear about them.

Thank you.

Comment: Hey @monglong, did you manage to solve your issue? I have similar issue where my intent is localised, included in all required targets, and still submit generates these issues.

Comment: @Mateusz Karwat
hello, I haven't solved it yet.

Comment: @Mateusz Karwat
I was wondering if the `Localizable.strings` file wasn't properly imported during the archiving process, so I checked inside the `ipa` file as well, but it was there as expected. (It seems to be a different issue).